# Предотвратить наследуемость цвета фона родителя для дочернего элемента

Tags: html, css, background

У меня есть такая структура html:

```
<p>
    p text
    <span>span text</span>
    <strong>strong text</strong>
    p text
</p>
```

Мне необходимо задать цвет фона для тега `<p>` таким образом, что бы этот цвет фона **не** затронул цвет фона дочерних тегов `<span>` и `<strong>`. Т.е. цвет фона тегов `<span>` и `<strong>` должен остаться прежним.

Это было бы очень просто сделать, если бы **p text** внутри тега `<p>` был бы обернут в какой-нибудь тег.
Но сделать это нужно с текущей структурой. Я перепробовал немало методов, используя `:not()`, `:is()` и т.д. Так же, "игрался" с правилами `revert`, `unset` и `intrial`. Пробовал `display: contents`. Тоже толку нет.

Javascript использовать нельзя. Так же, нельзя использовать атрибуты стилей `style` для тегов и назначать классы.
Конечно же, я знаю, что это проблему еще можно решить с помощью переменных CSS - `:root`. Но это тоже использовать нельзя. Потому, что у родителя тега `<p>`, в данном случае это тег тела, и он разбит на разные блоки с разными цветами фона.

Может кто ни будь знает секрет решения данной проблемы? Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Вот воспроизводимый пример:

```css
body {
    background: yellowgreen;
}

p {
    background: yellow;
}

p *:is(span, strong) {
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<p>
    p text
    <span>span text</span>
    <strong>strong text</strong>
    p text
</p>
```

Comment: У любого элемента по умолчанию фон прозрачный...  Не понятно, что именно тебе надо реализовать?

Comment: Исключения `input textarea button`

Comment: @Air, я хочу задать цвет фона для тега p так, что бы фон дочерних тегов был нетронут.

Comment: И при этом не задать самому дочернему элементу ни какого фонового цвета?

Comment: @Air, да, совершенно верно. Иначе было бы просто.

Comment: Ну тогда есть единственный вариант, собери команду и создай свой браузер....

Comment: Наверное максимум что тут можно навелосипедить - присвоить span, strong фоновый цвет как у body

Comment: @emptyman, да, можно, с помощью переменных цсс. И я думаю, что другого пути тут нет (

Comment: _"... в данном случае это тег тела, и он разбит на разные блоки с разными цветами фона."_ Это что такое? Как можно разбить тег на блоки? И, если такое возможно, почему нет полноценного примера?